# Flutter - Infinite Scroll & Images causes App Crash

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

We are building a product listing page in flutter and trying to load products as the user scrolls and reaches the end of the page. It's basically a grid view builder with network images. When i run the app using the profile mode, the app crashes once we have around 1300 images in the screen and if we run the app using the release mode, the app crashes once we have around 5000 images in the screen. Shouldn't the flutter GC kick in so that the images that are not in view is no longer held in memory?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Infinite Scroll Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Infinite Scroll Crash Sample'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController scrollController;
  bool autoReloadInProgress = false;
  int noOfElements = 50;
  String baseUrl = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0286/0344/9475/products/";
  
  // short list, actual list has thousands of image urls
  List<String> images = [
    "imagejpg_1024x1024_2x_032a1436-7cb4-42de-9289-ea58b510d750.jpg?v=1579293459",
    "Raven_Brow_Balm_1024x_fa88c686-8c89-4647-babb-440ef8292d5b.png?v=1577445154",
    "BioTuff_GeneralUseBinLinersMed25_8_1024_1024.jpg?v=1587709003",
    "34eyeshadow_neutralnude_1024x1024_2x_08d10c39-1c3f-431c-b03b-436f2ff55cfa.png?v=1579411298",
    "Ballet_1024x1024_a61af758-0757-454e-938f-96065d0c5e40.jpg?v=1581403220",
    "pure-organic-beeswax-tealight-refills.png?v=1586942441",
    "Holding_Cherry_Red_2000x2000_d6ce67a2-e740-4a99-b599-86196146400b.png?v=1577858762",
    "WCP-FNS1-004_1024x1024_2x_43f2e247-eecb-4a56-89c6-c3ecc8e3031e.jpg?v=1579295821",
    "BabyWipes20sfront2D_1024x_01ad5c64-1ff6-402c-9995-5b7489555029.jpg?v=1587698137",
    "imageedit_214_7359687840_1.png?v=1577437619",
    "Organic_Chocolate_Maple_Pecan_1800x_10844ae0-d26c-4946-ab8b-d8c8d166b37b.png?v=1577863201",
    "FACIAL_POLISH_1_1000x_87f987c5-95da-4fe9-9a83-0f8a3d4cd74a.jpg?v=1581373634",
    ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController = new ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _scrollListener() async{
    if(scrollController.position.extentAfter < 800) {
      setState(() {
        noOfElements += 50;
      });
    }
  }

  getProductGrid(){

    double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double aspectRatio = 0.64;
    double cardWidth = deviceWidth < 200.0 ? deviceWidth : (deviceWidth <= 375 ? 180 : 200);
    double cellHeight = cardWidth / aspectRatio;
    int cardCount = (deviceWidth/cardWidth).toInt();
    double extraWidth = deviceWidth - (cardWidth * cardCount);
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: noOfElements,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
      primary: false,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: cardCount, crossAxisSpacing: extraWidth / (cardCount-1),
          childAspectRatio: aspectRatio, mainAxisSpacing: 20
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
        return Container(
          //height: 200,
          //width: 200.0,
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text((index+1).toString(), textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              Image.network(baseUrl + images[index%images.length]),
            ],
          )
        );
      },
    );

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Scrollbar(
          child:ListView(
            controller: scrollController,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  getProductGrid(),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Have added the link to the sample code as it has lot of image source and it doesn't fit the character limitations of post. Any insight into the issue?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vHqawSw18HSWP-YV_39_fFfo_IUGgQPv/view?usp=sharing

Update - Working code

```
Scrollbar(
        child:CustomScrollView(
          controller: scrollController,
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          slivers: [
            SliverList(
             delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate([
                  //widgets go here
             ])
            )
          ]
       )
);
```

Comment: Might be related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26072, also this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29214

Comment: What is the average size of an image?

Comment: Why you have nested, Grid view inside the List view? Does your list view has other elements too?

Comment: @OMiShah yes the list view has other elements

Comment: Use Sliver widgets fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) and [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) is just an implementation of Slivers. However, if you'd like to implement a custom ScrollView, you'd need to use [Slivers](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/slivers). The way Slivers work is when child widgets are out of site from the viewport, elements and render objects are destroyed along with their states. A workaround that could work for this issue is to create a CustomScrollView using Slivers.